# ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql, datetime

So I'm trying to run a simple query that count the events of each user, within the past 12 months.
I have imported the date as a string (varchar), because if I use datetime it only adds null values into that column (ie. 0000-00-00)

```
CREATE table `DB`.`EVENTS`(user_id varchar(30)not null, datetime varchar(50) not null);
insert into `DB`.`EVENTS` VALUES ('1', 'Jun 14, 2020 3:35 PM'),
    ('2', 'Jun 3, 2020 3:35 PM'),
    ('2', 'May 17, 2020 1:00 PM'),
    ('3', 'Jan 5, 2020 2:00 PM'),
    ('4', 'Jun 3, 2020 12:00 PM'),
    ('5', 'Jun 24, 2020 5:00 PM'),
    ('3', 'Jan 15, 2019 2:00 PM');
```

so I need to convert the str to date and use a nested query (this query works on its own) :

```
select user_id, count(*) from DB.EVENTS where user_id in (select user_id, str_to_date(datetime, '%M %d,%Y') as date
    from DB.EVENTS
    having date >= DATE_ADD(current_timestamp(), interval -12 month));
```

but I'm getting the error ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s).
If I try to remove the column user_id I get null values again ...
Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: Your Subquery returns two columns, remove the `str_to_date(datetime, '%M %d,%Y')` calculation from the Select-list and move it into HAVING (or better WHERE)

Comment: If I remove it from the select part, then I get an error : ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'datetime' in 'having clause'

Comment: What exactly do you want? Currently you count *all* events of a user if he had *any* event within the last year. This can easily be done without subquery.

Comment: I'd like to count all the events for each user within the past 12 months. I don't want the dates in the output, but I need the date conversion/interval to be in the query.

Comment: Youn don't need to add a column to the Select list to use it in WHERE/HAVING.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate ? If I don't convert str_to_date in the select list and put it straight into the WHERE/HAVING clause it prints a null result...

Comment: Of course, you should apply the FORMAT in your import to store it as a date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count only the events of the last year, you filter in WHERE:

```
select user_id, count(*) 
from DB.EVENTS
where str_to_date(datetime, '%M %d,%Y') -- only rows from the last  
    >= DATE_ADD(current_timestamp(), interval -12 month)
group by user_id
;
```

If you want to count *all* events if the user had *any* event in the last year you can apply the logic in HAVING:

```
select user_id, count(*) 
from DB.EVENTS
group by user_id
having max(str_to_date(datetime, '%M %d,%Y')) -- any event in the last year 
    >= DATE_ADD(current_timestamp(), interval -12 month)
;
```